# Conclusions of The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra over $\Bbb{C}$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Conclude from the fundamental theorem of algebra that, over the complex numbers,  every real polynomial can be written as a multiplication of real polynomials of degree 1 or 2. I am completely confused here. I know there has got to be a root over C but however, I can't seem to find a way to approach this supposedly simple conclusion. I could really use some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a real polynomial $P$.
As conjugation preserve products and sums, we know that $\forall x\in\mathbb C,~P(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow P(\overline x)=0$.
Note that 
$$(X-x)(X-\overline x) = X^2 - 2Re(x)X + |x|^2 \quad (\star),$$
a real polynomial.

Starting from the factorisation $$P = \lambda \prod_{i=1}^p (X - x_i),$$
(given by the fundamental theorem) where $x_i\in\mathbb C$, you can reorder the terms so that either $x_i$ is real, else $x_i = \overline x_{i+1}$.

The terms with $x_i$ real are the degree 1 terms of the factorisation, and with $(\star)$, you have your terms of degree 2.

Comment: If $x$ is a root of $P$, then you can write $P = (X-x)Q$, where $Q$ is a polynomial. Inductively, over $\mathbb C$, you can write P as I said earlier, where $x_i$ are (complex) roots of $P$. There cannot be only one not real number among the $x_i$'s, because there is at least $\overline x_i$, which is a different complex (not real) number.

Comment: My bad, you are correct.